# Vagrant - PhpStorm - Laravel - HTTP Where can I access my local website?

Tags: vagrant, vagrantfile, homestead

I am new to to Php/Laravel and VMs world.

I booted up vagrant with this Vagrantfile:

```
# -*- mode: ruby -*-
# vi: set ft=ruby :

# All Vagrant configuration is done below. The "2" in Vagrant.configure
# configures the configuration version (we support older styles for
# backwards compatibility). Please don't change it unless you know what
# you're doing.
Vagrant.configure(2) do |config|
  # The most common configuration options are documented and commented below.
  # For a complete reference, please see the online documentation at
  # https://docs.vagrantup.com.

  # Every Vagrant development environment requires a box. You can search for
  # boxes at https://atlas.hashicorp.com/search.
  config.vm.box = "laravel/homestead"

  # Disable automatic box update checking. If you disable this, then
  # boxes will only be checked for updates when the user runs
  # `vagrant box outdated`. This is not recommended.
  # config.vm.box_check_update = false

  # Create a forwarded port mapping which allows access to a specific port
  # within the machine from a port on the host machine. In the example below,
  # accessing "localhost:8080" will access port 80 on the guest machine.
  # config.vm.network "forwarded_port", guest: 80, host: 8080

  # Create a private network, which allows host-only access to the machine
  # using a specific IP.
  # config.vm.network "private_network", ip: "192.168.33.10"

  # Create a public network, which generally matched to bridged network.
  # Bridged networks make the machine appear as another physical device on
  # your network.
  # config.vm.network "public_network"

  # Share an additional folder to the guest VM. The first argument is
  # the path on the host to the actual folder. The second argument is
  # the path on the guest to mount the folder. And the optional third
  # argument is a set of non-required options.
  config.vm.synced_folder "./devpeople", "/home/vagrant/devpeople"

  # Provider-specific configuration so you can fine-tune various
  # backing providers for Vagrant. These expose provider-specific options.
  # Example for VirtualBox:
  #
  # config.vm.provider "virtualbox" do |vb|
  #   # Display the VirtualBox GUI when booting the machine
  #   vb.gui = true
  #
  #   # Customize the amount of memory on the VM:
  #   vb.memory = "1024"
  # end
  #
  # View the documentation for the provider you are using for more
  # information on available options.

  # Define a Vagrant Push strategy for pushing to Atlas. Other push strategies
  # such as FTP and Heroku are also available. See the documentation at
  # https://docs.vagrantup.com/v2/push/atlas.html for more information.
  # config.push.define "atlas" do |push|
  #   push.app = "YOUR_ATLAS_USERNAME/YOUR_APPLICATION_NAME"
  # end

  # Enable provisioning with a shell script. Additional provisioners such as
  # Puppet, Chef, Ansible, Salt, and Docker are also available. Please see the
  # documentation for more information about their specific syntax and use.
  # config.vm.provision "shell", inline: <<-SHELL
  #   sudo apt-get update
  #   sudo apt-get install -y apache2
  # SHELL
end
```

I've tried expirimenting using vagrant commands from their documentation, plus modifying the Vagrantfile without success.

What I want is a similar "site mapping" expirience, just like when you edit the `Homestead.yaml` file. Plus what is supposed to be the default way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well I missed a vital step in the [laravel documentation](http://laravel.com/docs/5.2/homestead). The proper way to setup your vagrant box is by cloning the "setup" files from the 
laravel/homestead repository.

So in order to access the server you simply edit the `sites`, on the `Homstead.yaml` file.

Answer (score 1):

create a folder in your host machine something like

```
  c:/projects/devpeople
```

Modify your Vagrant file like this

```
 config.vm.box = "ubuntu/trusty64"


 config.vm.network "forwarded_port", guest: 80, host: 8080
```

or you can change the port like this

```
 config.vm.network "forwarded_port", guest: 80, host: 8081
```

see below

create a folder in your virtual machine

```
 vagrant up

 vagrant ssh

 cd  var/www

 mkdir devpeople
```

So your virtual machine should have a folder like this

```
  /var/www/devpeople
```

Then you can put your projects in your host machine

So the Vagrant sync folder will look like this

```
  config.vm.synced_folder "c:/projects/devpeople", "/var/www/devpeople"
```

Run 
    vagrant up

and access your development site

```
localhost:8081
```

If the folder does not "sync", run

```
vagrant halt
```

to restart vagrant

then

```
vagrant up
```

Comment: I specifically want homestead so I'll leave it as is. I'll get back to you as soon as I test your Answer. Thanks.

Comment: Nope, this doesn't work either. Folders are syncing no problem. Plus I don't think this is supposed to be the "right way".

Comment: So if thats what you, mean, you have to follow Laravel's docs on how to set up Homestead, you have to configure it in Homestead.yaml, not in Vagranfile.yaml.

Comment: Yes. In reality I did this procedure before I run into this problem. I followed a global homestead strategy. Then I tried to do a per project homestead. But I used the PhpStorm `Vagrant Init` command, which only generates a `Vagrantfile`. But then I realized that I should again `git clone` the homestead repository instead of just using `Vagrant Init`. Thanks Ian.

Comment: With the Vagranfile you provided above, does config.vm.box = "laravel/homestead" successfully installed? I never tried it before, I usually use UbuntuTrusty in a per project and manually configure vagrant machine(apache, mysql, etc).Maybe I will try that in my future projects.

Comment: You do whaaat? Never do that again Ian! Yes it works. But first, you have to `vagrant box add laravel/homestead`, but you need to do this only once, globally I mean.

Comment: good job Konstantinos Dimakis. I am using apache2 in some of my projects, laravel homestead is preconfigured with nginx..Inside my .vagrant.d , I have these two boxes, ubuntutrusty and laravel/homestead.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to forward ports from within your VM to the host. [Here is an example from my Vagrantfile for Payara](https://github.com/mikecroft/payara-vagrant/blob/master/Vagrantfile):

```
config.vm.network :forwarded_port, guest: 4848, host: 4849
config.vm.network :forwarded_port, guest: 8080, host: 8081
```

So because I know that Payara uses ports 4848 and 8080 by default, I have forwarded them to similar ports on my host (to avoid clashes).

So if I went to `http://localhost:4849` after running `vagrant up`, I would be redirected to port 4848 within the VM, as though it was running locally.

[Looking into the Laravel documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/homestead#ports), it looks like the following ports are the ones you need to make sure are available:

- SSH: 2222 → Forwards To 22
- HTTP: 8000 → Forwards To 80
- HTTPS: 44300 → Forwards To 443
- MySQL: 33060 → Forwards To 3306
- Postgres: 54320 → Forwards To 5432

The docs imply that this is done by default, though, so you may want to try using them first to make sure.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your quick Answer. Gonna try out the defaults first. I'll get back to you.

Comment: Nope this doesn't seem to work. :/ Thanks though. Maybe something else if off on my workspace. Btw I do have apache2 running on localhost on port 80. Also I've tried the instructions of the Laravel documentation and it worked, BUT it had nothing to do with `Vagrantfile`, it was the `Homestead.yaml` file. But I need this to make it work through Vagrantfile in a similar way.